# How to evaluate a ruby expression in a buffer

Tags: filetype-ruby

I believe that I once saw a plugin which allowed one to see the result of evaluating ruby expressions inside a buffer.

Eg, if I wrote a line like

```
3 + 2 # =>
```

and pressed the required magic keys, the line would change to:

```
 3 + 2 # => 5
```

I know that there are way to invoke `vim` from `irb`, but what I'm after is more like invoking `irb` from inside `vim`.

I can't find that plugin now - does such a thing indeed exist?

Comment: I just googled 'vim plugin ruby evaluate' and the first result is [this](https://github.com/kmdsbng/vim-ruby-eval) which according to the screencast in the readme is the plugin you're talking about...

Comment: Excellent, thank you!
Is the -1 because of a poor question or a lack of google-fu?

Comment: I'd say because of the lack of google-fu but it does not comes from me so I can't say for sure :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually several way to do that.

The first google result is the [vim-ruby-eval plugin](https://github.com/kmdsbng/vim-ruby-eval) which provides the `:RubyEval` command. Here is a screen cast coming from the README page of the plugin:

[image]

This plugin requires `+ruby` (`:echo has('ruby')` should return `1`)

---

You can also do this with the `xmpfilter` command provided by the [`rcodetools`](https://github.com/rcodetools/rcodetools) ruby gem. As [this blog post](http://commandercoriander.net/blog/2012/10/10/evaluate-lines-of-ruby-in-vim/) says, there is a vim plugin for `xpmfilter`: [vim-ruby-xmpfilter](https://github.com/t9md/vim-ruby-xmpfilter)

Note that the plugin doesn't provide default mappings you'll have to set them by yourself but the README as a good amount of example to help you.